# algorithms to calculate difference of any pair of 2 elements for a vector

Tags: python, algorithm, convolution

I have 2 big vectors "vec_x" and "vec_y" represent the x and y axis position of each point. Now want to generate a matrix (A) whose subscript represents the distance between 2 elements, e.g. A[3][1000] stores sqrt((vec_x(3)-vec_x(1000))^2 + (vec_y(3)-vec_y(1000))^2).

Does anyone have a quick algorithm?

Because A is huge and may not be able to store in memory. In addition, if I define the diagonal elements are all the same to a constant, say 999, and what I need is a vector whose element represents the sum of each line in A. Any idea?

Simple loop seems to be super slow.

Comment: If you need to write this kind of algorithms (simple operation performed many times in a loop) more often consider looking into Cython - [A quick Cython introduction](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2008/04/19/a-quick-cython-introduction/). Or you can try Numpy which allows you to perform vector operations which can speed up your code. But this time, as @FuzzyDuck pointed out, using `scipy.spatial.distance` will be probably the best choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scipy.spatial.distance` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html), and in particular, `cdist()`.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y = [4,1,7,8,1]
>>> xy = zip(x, y)
>>> xy
[(1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 7), (4, 8), (5, 1)]
>>> import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd
>>> ssd.cdist(xy, xy)
array([[ 0.        ,  3.16227766,  3.60555128,  5.        ,  5.        ],
       [ 3.16227766,  0.        ,  6.08276253,  7.28010989,  3.        ],
       [ 3.60555128,  6.08276253,  0.        ,  1.41421356,  6.32455532],
       [ 5.        ,  7.28010989,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  7.07106781],
       [ 5.        ,  3.        ,  6.32455532,  7.07106781,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Okay, I may be wrong. And how about the second step, because the big matrix is out of memory, say 1M * 1M.